# How to floor a floating point number? from 0.999 to 0.99

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to truncate any value that appears after two decimal places in Matlab/Octave.

I do not want the value 1. I instead want the value to be 0.99 after "rounding/flooring".

Please use only built-in functions to accomplish this task.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to matlab and I wanted a floor function that will retain two decimal digits after "flooring". I have tried sprintf(), round() and floor(). While the former two functions rounded the value to 1. Floor rounded it up to 0. While that is expected. I wanted a function that does not round it to the next digit. And so, I have posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale up the number, apply rounding, scale the result down by the same value:

```
x = 0.999;
y = floor (100 * x) / 100;
```